# Why does PySpark throw a JSONDecodeError when attempting to load a string from a Kafka topic to a dictionary?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am using [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) to read from a Kafka topic (records are in JSON format) with the intent of performing some transformations once I get the data into Spark. My first step is to read records from the topic as strings and then convert them to a dictionary (via the python `json` library) to perform transformations (I do not want to use the `to_json` capability within Spark because the format of the records in my Kafka topic may change and I do not want to use [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) which does not require a schema because there is no native functionality to write back to topics). I received a `JSONDecodeError` (below) when attempting to convert the strings.

Here are the components which produce my error:

I run the following PySpark Code locally:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def str_to_json(s):
    j = json.loads(s)
    return j

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("App Name") \
        .getOrCreate()

    strToJson = udf(str_to_json, StringType())

    spark.udf.register("strToJson", strToJson)

    df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "first_topic") \
        .load() \
        .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    df_transformed = df.withColumn('strToJson', strToJson('value'))

    query = df_transformed \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .start()
```

I then write a record to my Kafka topic using the `kafka-console-producer` also from my local machine in the following format:

```
'{"name":"bob"}'
```

The following error is then outputted to the console when Spark attempts to use the UDF to convert the value of a record (from the Kafka Topic) to a JSON/dictionary object within the PySpark job:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I added a couple debugging print statements within the UDF to see what value is being passed in:

```
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>

>>> print(s)
'{"name": "bob"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code to produce a json message to kafka console producer?

keep the json records in a file as below

```
[nsr@inlthome]$ cat > samplerecords.json
{"name": "bob"}
{"name": "john"}
```

and run console producer

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic first_topic < samplerecords.json
```

I have tried running the program below:
[image]

Comment: Awesome! This works, the issue is that I was including the quotes from my console producer: `'{"name": "bob"}'` instead of: `{"name": "bob"}` Thanks @nalanagula

Comment: If the answer helped you to resolve the issue, take a moment to accept to close the thread as resolved.